# In App Purchase Getting product details programmatically

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to get the price of In App Products programmatically?
I would like to show the price of the in app product on my buy button. Is there any service provided by android like "getInAppProductPrice(productId)".

The reason I need this is because, if I edit the price of a product at a later time, I would like to get it reflected in my application buy button automatically rather than hard code the price.

In the android market checkout screen, the price is shown. So some service should be available? Is it open to us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V3 of in app billing now has such helper functions, you want `getSkuDetails()`

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails

Unfortunately it does not support getting a list of all available products which would be nice to have

Answer (score 1):

[Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) was working fine till Dec 15th 2011. It is not working as of now.That API used to give information on the market app. You can retrieve data, but I have never heard of anything which would help the developer to programmatically change the pricing details.

Comment: I need not change the price programmatically. I just need to get the price of In App Products. Will this api help in getting information about the in app products or the application alone?

Comment: @firebolt7 The site says they have achieved the following things. Current progress: •You can browse market with any carrier or locale you want. •Search for apps using keywords or package name. **•Retrieve an app info using an app ID.** •Retrieve comments using an app ID. •Get PNG screenshots and icon ..... Better check what all app info details you are able to fetch. If you cant get pricing details, then you better mail any of the 6 developers at this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/people/list)